# Remove same values from two lists and compare them using List.fold in F#

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I am trying to create a function that takes two lists that removes values in one list that are also in the other. E.g if we have the lists [1;2;3] and [1;2;3;4] then the first list becomes empty []
and the second list is just [4]. At the end I just when to compare both lists.
I am trying to use List.fold for this since I want to understand it better. Also I created my own folder function that deletes elements from a list.
I am very new to F# so I only came up with a partial solution

```
let rec delete x list =
    match list with 
    | [] -> []
    | hd:: tl when hd = x -> tl
    | hd:: tl-> hd:: delete x tl


let myFunc list1 list2 = 
    let x = list1 |> List.fold(delete) [] list2
    let y = list2 |> List.fold(delete) [] list1    
    x = y
```

but this does not work and the compiler is telling me "The type '('a -> 'b)' does not support the 'equality' constraint because it is a function type"  when I try to use the delete function with the list.fold method.

Comment: You're giving `List.fold` too many arguments. It only takes three, but you're giving it four.

Comment: Also, think about the order of arguments of your `delete` function. The first should be the state of `List.fold`, which is a list, the second is an individual element. Bonus points for figuring out what happens when the discrepancies between the lists are significant (hint: [Tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)).

Comment: `List.fold` is basically a for-loop over a list where you mutate/build something else along the way. But `List.fold` eliminates the mutating variable, and passes it to a function on every turn. It is good that you want to know more about `List.fold`, but I think your example is not good fot his case. Its probably better to try to implement `fold`, `foldBack` and other `List` functions yourself to get a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 3):

Although you say you are trying to use `List.fold` for this to understand it better, there is another List function that makes this simpler. This is to use `List.except` which is one of a number of methods that treats lists as sets.

```
let list1 = [1;2;3] 
let list2 = [1;2;3;4] 

let myFunc list1 list2= 
    list1 |> List.except list2, list2 |> List.except list1

printfn "%A" (myFunc list1 list2) 

[],[4]
```

If you want to understand List.fold here you could try and create an explicit implementation of `except` using `List.fold`. However, again, this is simpler to implement using List.filter.

```
let list1 = [1;2;3] 
let list2 = [1;2;3;4] 

let except exclude src =
    src |> List.filter (fun i -> exclude |> List.contains i |> not)

let myFuncCustom list1 list2 = 
    (list1 |> except list2), (list2 |> except list1)

printfn "%A" (myFuncCustom list1 list2)

[],[4]
```

So really you want to implement `filter` using `List.fold`. In this case you would actually need `List.foldBack`:

```
let filter f src =  
    List.foldBack (fun item filtered  -> 
        if f item then item :: filtered else filtered) src []
```

You can use `List.fold` but then results are reversed and you need to pipe this into `List.rev`. And note that `List.fold` only takes three arguments: the first a `folder` function; second the accumulator which becomes the output - in this case a list too; and, the last, the source list to fold over. (Let us expand `List.contains` as well):

```
    let list1 = [1;2;3] 
    let list2 = [1;2;3;4] 
    
    let rec contains item  = function
        | [] -> false
        | hd::tl when  hd = item -> true
        | hd::tl -> contains item tl
    
    let filter f src =  
        src 
        |> List.fold (fun filtered item  -> 
            if f item then item :: filtered else filtered) []
        |> List.rev
    
    let except exclude src =
        src |> filter (fun i -> exclude |> contains i |> not)
    
    let myFuncCustom list1 list2 = 
        (list1 |> except list2), (list2 |> except list1)
    
    printfn "%A" (myFuncCustom list1 list2)

    [],[4]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you want:

```
let difference list blacklist =
    let folder acc a =
        if List.contains a blacklist
        then acc
        else a::acc
    List.fold folder [] list

difference [1;2;3;4] [1;2;3] // [4]
difference [1;2;3] [1;2;3;4] // []
```

Looking at the code you posted, there seems to be some confusion on how fold works.

- the arguments to fold are

  - A function that somehow combines a given state with an element of the list. This function can be as simple as summing the two arguments together resulting in a single scalar or it can be something really complicated that creates some weird data structure.
  - An initial state which must be of the type that you want fold to produce
  - And, of course, the list you want to fold over
- Fold iterates the list, by calling your fold function for every element of the list.
- The first time your fold function is called, it will get the initial state. Every other time it will get the state produced from the previous iteration.
- Fold will return the last state that was produced by your fold function (or the initial state if the list is empty)

Answer (score 1):

As your goal is to better understand `fold` I try to explain `fold` instead of explaining how you achive your goal.

`fold` is bacially a `for` loop for immutable data-types. It allows you to eliminate mutable variables. For example,
lets assume you want to sum all values of an integer list. In an "imperative" style you are probaly used to
write something like this.

```
(* This xs is used through all exampes *)
let xs = [1..10]

(* Example A1 *)
let mutable sum = 0
for x in xs do
    sum <- sum + x

(* sum = 55 *)
```

Before you loop through a list, you define a mutable `sum` and then mutate the sum and updating it on everey iteration.
This is how you achive it with `List.fold`.

```
(* Example A2 *)
let sum =
    List.fold (fun sum x ->
        sum + x
    ) 0 xs

(* sum = 55 *)
```

You can think of `List.fold` as the following.

1. The function is the body of the loop that gets executed for every item in your list.
2. The second argument to `List.fold` (here 0) is the state you want to compute. This is the sum.
3. The last argument of `List.fold` is finally the list you want to traverse.

The function always gets two arguments. The state and the next item of your list. Your function must return
the next state.

With the for-loop you also have state. But the state is outside of the for-loop and you achieve your goal
by mutating the state.

You also can think of the `List.fold` by mentally mapping the values to the lambda function you provide. The second
argument `0` will be `sum` in your lambda and `x` in your lambda is one value of `xs`. The result of your lambda is
the `sum` for the next call.

Let's say you want to compute three things on the fly. A mutable version looks like this

```
(* Helper Function *)
let isEven x = x &&& 1 = 0

(* Example B1 *)
let mutable count = 0
let mutable evens = 0
let mutable sum   = 0

for x in xs do
    count <- count + 1

    if isEven x then
        evens <- evens + 1

    sum <- sum + x

(* count=10; evens=5; sum=55 *)
```

Here we compute the amount of values in a list, how many even values exists, and the sum in one go.

`List.fold` only allows one state, but the state can be a complex value. For example a tuple with three values. The
same example with `List.fold` looks like this:

```
(* Example B2 *)
let count,evens,sum =
    List.fold (fun (count,evens,sum) x ->
        (count+1), (if isEven x then evens + 1 else evens), (sum + x)
    ) (0,0,0) xs

(* count=10; evens=5; sum=55 *)
```

To better understand fold it is crucial to understand recursion and immutable data-strucutres like how `list` works.
You could implement `fold` yourself like this:

```
(* Self-defined fold *)
let rec myFold f state xs =
    match xs with
    | []      -> state
    | x::rest -> myFold f (f state x) rest

(* Example C *)
let sum = myFold (fun sum x -> sum + x) 0 xs

(* sum = 55 *)
```

`fold` just do two things, it checks if the list is empty and in that case returns the `state`. Or it removes one element from the top of your list and calls itself recursively by

1. Keeping the function.
2. Producing the next state with `(f state x)`
3. Use the remaining list `rest`

Maybe you wonder about performance. This is tail-recursive, and tail-recursive functions are basically turned into for-loops by the compiler. So it has no performance penalty compared to the code that mutate things.

This is at least the case in F#. Just a reminder, not every compiler or run-time for other languages support tail-recursion.